# updated mysql to 5.6 from 5.1, but the php info still showing 5.1 client version

Tags: php, mysql

Evnironment: centos6.6, using virtualmin sh install everything, originally the php is PHP Version 5.3.3, mysql 5.1.72, but i want to update mysql to 5.6, so i remove mysql, and install 5.6 using these commands

```
# yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
# yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server mysql-utilities
```

originally

```
mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql-devel-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```

Now

```
mysql-connector-python-2.0.2-1.el6.noarch
mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql-community-devel-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-server-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-common-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-utilities-1.5.3-1.el6.noarch
php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64
```

here is the php info

**mysql**

Client API version  5.1.72

**mysqli**

Client API library version  5.1.72

What am i missing, anyone knows?

OTHER INFO

removed mysql5.6 again

```
[root@centos1 modules]# ls
curl.so      imap.so      pdo_odbc.so    pgsql.so    wddx.so       xsl.so
dom.so       json.so      pdo_pgsql.so   phar.so     xmlreader.so  zip.so
fileinfo.so  mbstring.so  pdo.so         snmp.so     xmlrpc.so
gd.so        odbc.so      pdo_sqlite.so  sqlite3.so  xmlwriter.so
```

after reinstalled mysql5.6 again

```
[root@centos1 modules]# ls
curl.so      json.so      pdo_mysql.so   pgsql.so    xmlreader.so
dom.so       mbstring.so  pdo_odbc.so    phar.so     xmlrpc.so
fileinfo.so  mysqli.so    pdo_pgsql.so   snmp.so     xmlwriter.so
gd.so        mysql.so     pdo.so         sqlite3.so  xsl.so
imap.so      odbc.so      pdo_sqlite.so  wddx.so     zip.so

[root@centos1 mysql]# ls
libmysqlclient.a        libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0  libmysqlclient.so.16      libmysqlservices.a
libmysqlclient_r.a      libmysqlclient_r.so.18      libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0  plugin
libmysqlclient_r.so     libmysqlclient_r.so.18.1.0  libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient_r.so.16  libmysqlclient.so           libmysqlclient.so.18.1.0
```

Comment: reboot apache/php/_ampp?

Comment: 1) Definitely reboot, then re-check.  2) It's possible you inadvertently did a parallel install (instead of an "update") - and that *both* versions are installed - and the 5.1 version is the one still running/still talking to PHP.

Comment: i had run yum remove mysql*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed php-mysql, and use mysql-nd instead through webtatic repo

Answer (score 0):

php-mysql use libmysql. and maybe your mysql-libs are not upgraded.

answer for auther's reply

php-mysql make extension module mysql.so (maybe locate /usr/lib64/php)

mysql.so link libmysqlclient.so.16

libmysqlclient.so.16 is client lib for mysql 5.1 and i think this file not deleted.

maybe libmysqlclient locate /usr/lib64/mysql and you install another version of mysql
you can see another version of libmysqlclient.

backup libmysqlclient.so.16 and copy another version to libmysqlclient.so.16.

maybe it works. but not guaranteed it works well.

Comment: see my update, there are many libmysqlclient* inside the folder, which one is using?

Comment: in my server, libmysqlclient.so.16 is symbolic link. and so.XX.XX.XX is real file. maybe 16 is version 5.1 and 18 is version 5.6 
change symbolic link and check version like 
php -i | grep "Client API version"

Comment: neither rename or create another symlink ,it not works

Comment: libmysqlclient.so.16 is just my case. maybe your mysql.so has another link. rename each libmysqlclient and run php -i. if currect file renamed you can see warning message like this 
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0". if you find that file. make symlink

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a big favor and

1) Reboot

2) Check your logs; make sure the mysql daemon starts after reboot (and make sure it's the mysql daemon you expect)

... AND, FINALLY ...

3) Verify you have one - and only one - mysql installed.

For example:

*yum list installed | grep -i mysql*

```
mysql.x86_64                        5.1.69-1.el6_4                     installed
mysql-bench.x86_64                  5.1.69-1.el6_4                     installed
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64         5.1.5r1144-7.el6                   installed
mysql-devel.x86_64                  5.1.69-1.el6_4                     installed
mysql-libs.x86_64                   5.1.69-1.el6_4                     installed
mysql-server.x86_64                 5.1.69-1.el6_4                     installed
perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64               4.013-3.el6                        installed
php-mysql.x86_64                    5.3.3-23.el6_4                     installed
```

Comment: will the problem caused by i copy all old tables to /var/lib/mysql/mysql?

Comment: No, "copying all the old files" might cause *other* problems - but not a version ID mismatch.  Q: HAVE YOU DONE THE REBOOT AND LOOKED AT THE LOGS???  Q: HAVE YOU RUN "run list installed" AND LOOKED AT THE OUTPUT???

Comment: i reinstalled mysql again, the php still showing mysql 5.1.72

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with it displaying 5.1 for the client version.

Redhat maintains a Software Collections repository which is offered downstream for CentOS 6.x.

It contains more recent versions of MySQL, PHP etc. than the versions contained in the standard distribution. The newer versions are fully supported but the notes say that the newer MySQL version (5.5) is expected to use the MySQL client (5.1) from the standard distribution even though the 5.5 client is installed along with the 5.5 daemon.

When you installed 5.6 from the mysql repo, it installed packages with a different naming scheme than the core packages:
Old: mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (mysql-server-xxx)
New: mysql-community-server-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql-community-server-xxx)

To replace the old version you would install:
mysql-server-5.6.22-2.el6.x86_64 (not mysql-community-server...)

So the core MySQL client may still be there and the system is configured to use the core MySQL client even with a newer server version.

[Red Hat Software Collections 1.0 Release Notes, 1.4. Known Issues](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html-single/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html#sect-RHSCL-Known_Issues)

**1.4. Known Issues**
...
mariadb, mysql, postgresql **components**

> Red Hat Software Collections contains the MySQL 5.5, MariaDB 5.5 and
>   PostgreSQL 9.2 databases. The core Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 provides
>   earlier versions of these databases (client library and daemon).
>   Client libraries are also used in database connectors for dynamic
>   languages, libraries etc.
>
> Client libraries packaged in the Red Hat Software Collections database
>   packages are not supposed to be used as they are included only for
>   purposes of server utilities and the daemon. **Users are instead
>   expected to use the system libraries and database connectors provided
>   with the core system.**
>
> A protocol which is used between the client library and the daemon is
>   stable across database versions, so using, **for example, the MySQL 5.1
>   client library with the MySQL 5.5 daemon works as expected.**

[CentOS Documentation: The Software Collections ( SCL ) Repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL)